# Setting overlay image causes image to shrink

Tags: css, css-position

I've got an overlay image that I am trying to position to bottom of its div. If I don't set a height it covers the screen (like it should) but is too high.

If I set a height, it goes from https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH3UT.png to https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjj6D.png.

Code

```
#home {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 250px; <- setting this causes it
}
```

Within my body I have

```
body {
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML Code

```
 <section id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img src="assets/img/shape.svg" class="overlay">
        </div>
 </section>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By setting the height, the image is just resizing as you've told it to.  Remove the height and on `.overlay` just set your `bottom` position to whatever negative value you're happy with.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, seems that just pushes it above the other content :/ am I able to stretch it somehow ?

Comment: Can you shove your code on https://codepen.io/ and I can have a look there?